# Is it possible to use dependencied in build.gradle from a repo?

Tags: android, gradle

I am using a library which requires the implementing app need to implement several dependencies.

EG:. Every app which implements that library need to implement all the dependencies in the `baselibraries`. I wrote this in a `dependencies.gradle` file and implemnting the dependency as `apply from: 'dependencies.gradle'` and `implementation baseadlibraries`

What I want to know is whether it is possible to host the  `dependencies.gradle` in jcenter() and use it like another plugin. I tried but it is not working.

**dependencies.gradle**

`````
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
    ext.room_version = "2.2.5"
    ext.koin_version = "2.1.5"
    ext.navigation_version = '2.2.2'

    junit4Version = "4.12"

    libraries = [
            appcompat         : "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha01",
            constraintLayout  : 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3',
            legacySupport     : 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0',
            kotlinStdLib      : "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version",
            ktxCore           : 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0',
            materialLib       : 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0',
            workMgrKtx        : 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.3.4',
            firebaseAds       : 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:19.1.0',
            firebaseMessaging : 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.7',
            firebaseConfig    : 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config-ktx:19.1.4',
            firebaseAnalytics : 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:17.4.2',
            crashlytics       : 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0',
            glide             : 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1',

            koinViewModel     : "org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:$koin_version",
            koinAndroid       : "org.koin:koin-android:$koin_version",

         

            navigationFragment: "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation_version",
            navigationUi      : "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation_version",
            lifecycleXtn      : 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0',

            room              : "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version",
            roomKtx           : "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version",
            roomKapt          : "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version",
            preferences       : "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1",
            playCore          : 'com.google.android.play:core:1.7.2'

    ]

    baselibraries = [
            libraries.appcompat,
            libraries.constraintLayout,
            libraries.kotlinStdLib,
            libraries.ktxCore,
            libraries.legacySupport,
            libraries.koinViewModel,
            libraries.koinAndroid,
            libraries.navigationFragment,
            libraries.navigationUi,
            libraries.playCore
    ]

    baseadlibraries = [
            baselibraries
            libraries.firebaseAnalytics,
            libraries.firebaseAds,
            libraries.preferences
    ]

}````
`````